# nutch-1.18 error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nutch/storage/WebPage$Field

Tags: java, nutch

I still have the same error on all versions of binary nutch, sources or git
Source versions compile with this constant error :

**ant runtime**

```
...
resolve-default:
[ivy:resolve] impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
[ivy:resolve] impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator in [] nor Ivy classloader
[ivy:resolve] impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
[ivy:resolve] impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = /home/user/Téléchargements/nutch/branch-1.18/ivy/ivysettings.xml
...
but 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 36 seconds
```

when i type :   **bin/nutch inject base/crawldb urls/**

```
021-05-07 23:00:18,306 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local829319691_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nutch/storage/WebPage$Field
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nutch/storage/WebPage$Field
    at org.apache.nutch.scoring.opic.OPICScoringFilter.<clinit>(OPICScoringFilter.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:164)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.getOrderedPlugins(PluginRepository.java:442)
    at org.apache.nutch.scoring.ScoringFilters.<init>(ScoringFilters.java:46)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector$InjectMapper.setup(Injector.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.storage.WebPage$Field
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginClassLoader.loadClassFromSystem(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginClassLoader.loadClassFromParent(PluginClassLoader.java:92)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:72)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 18 more
2021-05-07 23:00:19,027 INFO  mapreduce.Job - Job job_local829319691_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2021-05-07 23:00:19,490 INFO  mapreduce.Job - Counters: 17
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=3158671488622
        FILE: Number of bytes written=11186329660
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=0
        Map output records=0
        Map output bytes=0
        Map output materialized bytes=81536
        Input split bytes=982778
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=1515713
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=20589437779968
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
2021-05-07 23:00:19,491 ERROR crawl.Injector - Injector job did not succeed, job status: FAILED, reason: NA
2021-05-07 23:00:19,498 ERROR crawl.Injector - Injector: java.lang.RuntimeException: Injector job did not succeed, job status: FAILED, reason: NA
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:444)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:535)
```

Settings are default to eliminate a source of configuration error.
I have the same errors with nutch-1.17 and nutch-1.16.

Do you have any idea to help me?

Answer (score 0):

The class org.apache.nutch.storage.WebPage isn't part of Nutch 1.18 (1.16 or 1.17), it is contained in Nutch 2.x which isn't maintained anymore. This means that parts of the Nutch 2 code base are on the Java classpath. In detail, the OPIC scoring plugin loaded is not that of Nutch 1.18 but belongs to Nutch 2.x. To fix the issue, make sure the Java classpath is "clean" and that the correct `bin/nutch` script is called (that of Nutch 1.18 and not another one which is somehow on the PATH).

Comment: Hello Sebastian,

Indeed it was the property of "plugin.folders" that I copied and pasted forgetting to modify the path in nutch-site.xml.
I had to recompile because of a URLNormalyser error and everything is back to normal. My nutch is working.

I just have to inject the 3 billion urls that I had registered in Hbase. I don't know how to code in java.

Thank you for your help. It feels good not knowing you're alone after many hours of searching.

I wish you a nice day.